# view dependency / reference in storyboard auto layout

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout

Can you reference a view in AutoLayout in Storyboard? 
In the "constant" field, I want to enter something like `myCustomView.width + 14`.

Is there a way to get this dependency?

[image]

Comment: unfortunately no. You would have to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an @IBOutlet on your MyCustomView class definition like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var platzHalterLogoTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

then tie that constraint, using the interface builder.

You will define an initial value on your storyboard, and then programatically change it when you need to.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
   super.viewDidAppear()
   platzHalterLogoTrailingConstraint.constant = calculateTrailingConstant()
}
```

Comment: ok. How would you then to that programmatically? I want something like that: `platzHalterLogoTrailingConstraint.constant = viewB.widthAnchor + playtzHalterLogoWidthAnchor / 2` But I can not divide an `anchor` by an `Int`.